# background refuses to fit entire page CSS

Tags: html, css

So i have a background thats 2300px long.. yet when the more button is clicked and the page extends, the background stops at around 1400px.
Here is the site in question. http://morzi.com/constantine/index.php
This is very frustrating as everything was working perfect yesterday, i did some minor adjustments and everything went to hell and now im stumped.

i just want the background to continue all the way down the page
Thanks!

Comment: managed to fix this issue. but another popped up, on non widescreen displays the page doesnt load properly, about 200px on the right side are cut off.. any ideas?

Comment: If you don't already have your code in source control, do it.  When you get into trouble, you can use dif to find the changes and optionally roll back.

Comment: definetly source control

Comment: can you guys send me in the right direction? i googled it but am not getting many helpful links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to set the background image size property?

Something like

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

Or have a similar solution to this one:

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I added the background to the HTML CSS and it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: it says i can do it in 2 days